# Handling of carriage return (\r) character in Python's Fabric

Tags: python, fabric, carriage-return

I am using Python's Fabric to execute some tasks on remote hosts through ssh.
One of the tasks uses carriage return character in its output, when displaying progress-bars of sub-tasks. Something similar to this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

        int i;

        for (i = 0; i <= 5; ++i) {
                printf("\rProgress: %d%%", (int)(100 * ((float)i / 5)));
                fflush(stdout);
                sleep(1);
        }
        printf("\n");

        return 0;
}
```

When this runs with python's Fabric:

```
def some_task():
    with settings(user = 'root'):
        run('./task_with_progress_bar.out')

tasks.execute(some_task, hosts = ['server_name'])
```

Fabric will ignore the `\r`, and instead of having the progress bar in one line, what I'll get is:

```
[server_name] Executing task 'some_task'
[server_name] run: ./task_with_progress_bar.out
[server_name] out:
[server_name] out: Progress: 0%
[server_name] out: Progress: 20%
[server_name] out: Progress: 40%
[server_name] out: Progress: 60%
[server_name] out: Progress: 80%
[server_name] out: Progress: 100%
[server_name] out:
```

It seems like `\r` is being treated as `\n`...

It the example above it's not too bad, but the actual task I am running is filled with progress bars that progress with smaller steps, and this pollutes the entire console with unnecessary output.

Is there a way to somehow customize the output so that Fabric will not ignore the `\r`, but still keep the same general format of: `[<server_name>] <action_being_taken>`? I like this format, it's neat and clean.

Comment: Do you want to suppress the progress output but not the others output?

Comment: No. I don't to suppress the output. I still want it to be displayed in the format `[server_name] <action_being_taken>`, only that the progress bar will not be printed in multiple lines. I want it to be printed in one line that shows progress...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that fabric is transforming `\r` in `\n`.

A workaround to this problem is to create a file like class and pass it as `stdout` argument to `run`, so we can process the output produced by the called program and translate `\n` back to `\r`. The challenge of writing such class is to identify which `\n` must be translated to `\r`. Here is attempt that looks for `"Progress:"` to identify such cases:

```
class FixProgress:
    def __init__(self):
        self.saw_progress = False

    def write(self, s):
        if 'Progress:' in s:
            self.saw_progress = True
        if s == '\n' and self.saw_progress:
            sys.stdout.write('\r')
            self.saw_progress = False
        else:
            sys.stdout.write(s)

    def flush(self):
        sys.stdout.flush()

def some_task():
    with settings(user = 'root'):
        run('./task_with_progress_bar.out', stdout = FixProgress())
```

This worked correctly with the c program in the question.

Comment: Setting `pty = False` did not do the trick, and I can't suppress the output since the output is necessary for the user to see (e.g. when some input  from the user is required)...

Comment: elegant solution, and exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: btw, how do you know what arguments does `run()` take? The doc (http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.11/api/core/operations.html?highlight=run#fabric.operations.run) only shows `*args, **kwargs` but doesn't specify...

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the source code of the c file that outputs the progress bar, you could test if stdin is a tty by using isatty().  If false you could suppress the progress bar output to only update at certain values, i.e. intervals of 25.

http://linux.die.net/man/3/isatty